# Javascript function to run every 2 minutes without loading another page

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Hi I am very new to javascript, I have a small peice of javascript which gets the lat and lon of using geolocation and then passes it to a php page.

What i want to do is run the function every two minutes, but each time the function runs it loads the test.php page

my code is below

```
  function position(){
  var a=setTimeout(position(),60000)
  }


    if(navigator.geolocation)
      {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
      {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = position.coords.longitude;
      document.location = "locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + 
                   lon;

      });
  }
```

Is there away of passing the variables to the php page without loading it?, or what would be the best way to call the javascript function to update the details every two minutes.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started, if you use jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a bug in your code above, probably a typo.

```
var a=setTimeout(position(),60000)  <-- calling the function, not assigning it.
```

It should be

```
var a=setTimeout(position,60000);
```

Now to answer your question:

Make an Ajax call to the server.

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  //not the cross browser way of doing it
xmlHttp.open("GET", "locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, true); 
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you the ajax, solution worked perfectly, but it doesn't update automatically after 1 minute

Comment: What doesn't update? The page? You would need to handle the response and deal with the output in some manner.